# Usar resultado de un SELECT como nombre de tabla para otro SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla del siguiente estilo

Padre

```
|----|------- |-------|
| id | precio | tabla |
|----|------- |-------|
|1   | 50     | sxt   |
|----|------- |-------|
|2   | 45     | ext   |
|----|------- |-------|
```

luego tengo otras tablas

```
|----------------|
| detallessxt    |
|----------------|
| movimientosxt  |
|----------------|
| detallesext    |
|----------------|
| movimientosext |
|----------------|
```

actualmente desde el webservice hago  una consulta a padre y almaceno la variable tabla y luego hago un SELECT sobre el correspondiente detalles y movimientos, concatenando el nombre de la tabla.

```
"SELECT * FROM Detalles"+tabla+" WHERE ID=1"
"SELECT * FROM Movimientos"+tabla+" WHERE ID=1"
```

pero estoy buscando una forma de hacer esto con un procedimiento almacenado

pero no encuentro como anidar los selects

para obtener por ejemplo

```
CALL obtenertodo(id);
```

y que me retorne

```
|-------------------|
| id                |
|-------------------|
| precio            |
|-------------------|
| detalles_attr1    |
|-------------------|  
| movimientos_attr2 |
|-------------------|
```

no tengo acceso a la estructura de la base de datos, esta diseñada de una manera y solo tengo permisos para usar `SELECT`, generar funciones y procedimientos almacenados

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una situación especial donde no se tiene acceso a realizar modificaciones a la estructura de la base de datos, en general no debe de realizarse y en caso de encontrar una base de datos con una estructura similar primero advertir al administrador de la base de datos de que es una mala practica.

ahora bien esta es solo una "solución" si lo único que quieres es consumir la base de datos.

se usa una sentencia preparada, para poder ejecutar una sentencia desde un String

```
BEGIN
    SELECT tabla FROM padre 
    WHERE id= 1
    INTO @tabla;

    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM padre as p
                        INNER JOIN detalles', @tabla, 'AS d ON d.id=p.id
                        INNER JOIN Movimientos', @tabla, 'AS m ON m.id=p.id
                        WHERE p.id=1');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es hace un uso de inner join ó left join, de acuerdo a como indicas en tu esquema tus tablas hijo deberian tener el id de tu tabla padre para tener una relación de uno a muchos con lo cual puedes hacer algo similar a:

```
select
   Padre.*,
   Hijo1.*,
   Hijo2.*,
   ...
   HijoN
from
     Padre
inner join
     Hijo1
on
     Padre.Id == Hijo1.PadreId
inner join
     Hijo2
on
     Padre.Id = Hijo2.PadreId
....
etc
```

Comment: El problema es que no tengo acceso a la estructura de la base de datos, yo no la diseñe solo la consumo. por eso necesito armar un query tan extraño

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez Te recomiendo que solicites el esquema de la base, sin eso es posible que los query mas simples no puedan realizarse. Ya que no conoces ninguna de las claves foráneas o las relaciones entre tablas.